# Error creating elements

Tags: javascript

my code doesn't want to create the elements in the right way i want it to
and it doesn't create anything at all

so guys can anyone help me with it ???

```js
function creat_inputs() {
        var crsk=document.getElementById('skills_input');
        var skills=document.getElementById('skills_num').value;
        var count = $("#skills_input").children().length;
        var di=document.createElement("div");
        di.className='input-group in_group';
        var g=document.createElement("input");
        crsk.appendChild(di);
         g.className='form-control';
         g.setAttribute("type","text");
         g.setAttribute("placeholder","The Skill...");
        while (count != skills) {
            if (count > skills) {
               crsk.removeChild(crsk.lastChild);
                count--;
                document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML=document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML+">";
            }
            if (count < skills) {    
            crsk.appendChild(di);
            di.appendChild(g);
            count++;
            document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML=document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML+"<";
            }
            if (count === skills) {
                document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML=document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML+"=";
               break;
            
            }
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<input onkeyup="creat_inputs()" id="skills_num" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="How Many Skills :">
<div id="skills_input" style="text-align: center">
</div>
<p id="pp"></p>
```

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined",` - did you forget to include `jquery`

Comment: Why are you mixing Native JavaScript and jQuery? you can use either of them to perform the desired opeartion

Comment: @JaromandaX 
i didn't forget to include jquery

Comment: @Satpal 
is it wrong to use both ?

Comment: No, it not wrong as JQuery is JavaScript

Comment: @MagedGawad - see the error In my first comment - yes, you did forget to include jquery, at least in the runnable code snippet you presented in the question - and when you fix that, you'll see another error `"message": "TypeError: Not enough arguments to Node.appendChild."` - debugging 101 - browser developer tools console

Comment: It should be `lastChild` and not `lastchild`, case matters.

Comment: i edited it but it's not working well

Answer (score 0):

You appended the same element over and over. You have to create new elements each time:

```js
function creat_inputs() {
  var crsk = document.getElementById('skills_input');
  var skills = document.getElementById('skills_num').value;
  var count = crsk.children.length;
  while (count != skills) {
    if (count > skills) {
      crsk.removeChild(crsk.lastChild);
      count--;
      document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML + ">";
    }
    if (count < skills) {
      var di = document.createElement("div");
      di.className = 'input-group in_group';
      var g = document.createElement("input");
      g.className = 'form-control';
      g.setAttribute("type", "text");
      g.setAttribute("placeholder", "The Skill...");
      crsk.appendChild(di);
      di.appendChild(g);
      count++;
      document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML + "<";
    }
    if (count === skills) {
      document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML + "=";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="creat_inputs()" id="skills_num" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="How Many Skills :">
<div id="skills_input" style="text-align: center">
</div>
<p id="pp"></p>
```

I replaced the only line using jQuery with `var count = crsk.children.length;`.